# What's the difference between UIBackgroundTaskInvalid and endBackgroundTask?

Tags: ios, swift, background-task, background-mode, backgroundtaskidentifier

I sometimes see code where the task is ended using

```
bgTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

At other places I see

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bgTaskID)
```

At some other places I see:

```
  UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTaskID)
  backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

What's the difference between these three? Reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571327/what-does-uibackgroundtaskinvalid-mean) it seems it's just a matter of clean code, but I find that unnecessary, you've ended the task!

To me they are all the same. Only that using you `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid` you can validate if a task has ended or not. Not sure why you'd ever need to validate though.

Is the above assessment correct?

Comment: The first one doesn't end any task, you could do it after the task is ended so that you don't have a property pointing to the id of a task that is no longer valid.

Comment: I wrote a blog post myself years later. Check it out here: https://mfaani.com/posts/uiapplication-backgroundtasks-through-the-lens-of-closures/